# Catch exception and continue try block in Python

Tags: python, exception

Can I return to executing the `try` block after exception occurs?

For example:

```
try:
    do_smth1()
except:
    pass

try:
    do_smth2()
except:
    pass
```

vs.

```
try:
    do_smth1()
    do_smth2()
except:
    ??? # magic word to proceed to do_smth2() if there was exception in do_smth1
```

Comment: You cannot return to a `try` block once interrupted, no.

Comment: I think no. Some structure have to segment flow, and specify next point to execute at (`do_smth2` in this snippet) .

Comment: possible duplicate of [A Pythonic way for "resume next" on exceptions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655481/a-pythonic-way-for-resume-next-on-exceptions)

Comment: @MartijnPieters thats right, I googled too bad ;(

Comment: if you aren't even going to check to see if do_smth1 took an exception or not... then do_smth1 should eat the exception itself and not pass it up. but probably, you do care, and this isn't the right flow.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

No, you cannot do that.  That's just the way Python has its syntax.  Once you exit a try-block because of an exception, there is no way back in.

What about a for-loop though?

```
funcs = do_smth1, do_smth2

for func in funcs:
    try:
        func()
    except Exception:
        pass  # or you could use 'continue'
```

Note however that it is considered a bad practice to have a bare `except`.  You should catch for a specific exception instead.  I captured for `Exception` because that's as good as I can do without knowing what exceptions the methods might throw.

Comment: At the very least catch Exception.  This catches most exceptions but ignores SystemExit and KeyboardInterrupt which you almost never want to catch except possibly at the top level of your program.

Comment: this will not work if the do_smth1 internally has an exception where after catching it i want to continue inside do_smth1 right?

Comment: Today for unknown reason my try/except gets out of the for loop entirely and I have clue why. MY code worked for the past two week and then today just decide to end the for loop...

Answer (score 48):

While the other answers and the accepted one are correct and should be followed in real code, just for completeness and humor, you can try the `fuckitpy` ( https://github.com/ajalt/fuckitpy ) module.

Your code can be changed to the following:

```
@fuckitpy
def myfunc():
    do_smth1()
    do_smth2()
```

Then calling `myfunc()` would call `do_smth2()` even if there is an exception in `do_smth1())`

Note: Please do **not** try it in any real code, it is blasphemy

Comment: This is an ideal hack, although as you said, definitely not to be released in real code. The only down point (which I haven't managed to work around) is that this cannot access global variables, unlike the `try/except` methods, or the `with fuckit:` (The `fuckit` decorator seems more useful than the `with fuckit:`).

Comment: This is true genius. Probably the product of a terrible work environment.

Answer (score 26):

You can achieve what you want, but with a different syntax. You can use a "finally" block after the try/except. Doing this way, python will execute the block of code regardless the exception was thrown, or not.

Like this:

```
try:
    do_smth1()
except:
    pass
finally:
    do_smth2()
```

But, if you want to execute do_smth2() only if the exception was not thrown, use a "else" block:

```
try:
    do_smth1()
except:
    pass
else:
    do_smth2()
```

You can mix them too, in a  try/except/else/finally clause.
Have fun!

Answer (score 17):

'continue' is allowed within an 'except' or 'finally' only if the try block is in a loop. 'continue' will cause the *next* iteration of the loop to start.

So you can try put your two or more functions in a list and use loop to call your function.

Like this:

```
funcs = [f,g]
for func in funcs:
    try: func()
    except: continue
```

[For full information you can go to this link](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2005-July/040116.html)

Answer (score 9):

You could iterate through your methods...

```
for m in [do_smth1, do_smth2]:
    try:
        m()
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 8):

one way you could handle this is with a generator.  Instead of calling the function, yield it;  then whatever is consuming the generator can send the result of calling it back into the generator, or a sentinel if the generator failed:  The trampoline that accomplishes the above might look like so:

```
def consume_exceptions(gen):
    action = next(gen)
    while True:
        try:
            result = action()
        except Exception:
            # if the action fails, send a sentinel
            result = None

        try:
            action = gen.send(result)
        except StopIteration:
            # if the generator is all used up, result is the return value.
            return result
```

a generator that would be compatible with this would look like this:

```
def do_smth1():
    1 / 0

def do_smth2():
    print "YAY"

def do_many_things():
    a = yield do_smth1
    b = yield do_smth2
    yield "Done"
```

```
>>> consume_exceptions(do_many_things())
YAY
```

Note that `do_many_things()` does *not* call `do_smth*`, it just yields them, and `consume_exceptions` calls them on its behalf

Comment: It looks clever but I am not sure if this technique has any practical advantages over simpler function `def catch_exceptions(function: Callable[[], Any]) -> Any: ...` and instead of using yeilds do directly: `a = catch_exceptions(do_smth1)` ...

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you want to do this. The correct way to use a `try` statement in general is as precisely as possible. I think it would be better to do:

```
try:
    do_smth1()
except Stmnh1Exception:
    # handle Stmnh1Exception

try:
    do_smth2()
except Stmnh2Exception:
    # handle Stmnh2Exception
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on where and how often you need to do this, you could also write a function that does it for you:

```
def live_dangerously(fn, *args, **kw):
    try:
        return fn(*args, **kw)
    except Exception:
        pass

live_dangerously(do_smth1)
live_dangerously(do_smth2)
```

But as other answers have noted, having a null `except` is generally a sign something else is wrong with your code.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with `exec()` in a custom function, a list of strings, and a `for` loop.

The function with `exec()`:

```
def try_it(string):
    try:
        exec(string)
        print(f'Done: {string}')
    except:
        print(f'Error. Could not do: {string}')
```

More on exec():
[exec(*object*)

This function supports dynamic execution of Python code. *object* must be either a string or a code object.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec)

Example list of strings and `for` loop:

```
do_smth_list = ['do_smth1()', 'do_smth2()', 'do_smth3()'] 

for smth in do_smth_list:
    try_it(smth)
```

Answer (score 1):

**special_func** to avoid try-except repetition:

```
def special_func(test_case_dict):
    final_dict = {}
    exception_dict = {}

    def try_except_avoider(test_case_dict):

        try:
            for k,v in test_case_dict.items():
                final_dict[k]=eval(v) #If no exception evaluate the function and add it to final_dict

        except Exception as e:
            exception_dict[k]=e #extract exception
            test_case_dict.pop(k)
            try_except_avoider(test_case_dict) #recursive function to handle remaining functions

        finally:  #cleanup
            final_dict.update(exception_dict)
            return final_dict #combine exception dict and  final dict

    return try_except_avoider(test_case_dict)
```

Run code:

```
def add(a,b):
    return (a+b)
def sub(a,b):
    return (a-b)
def mul(a,b):
    return (a*b)

case = {"AddFunc":"add(8,8)","SubFunc":"sub(p,5)","MulFunc":"mul(9,6)"}
solution = special_func(case)
```

Output looks like:

```
{'AddFunc': 16, 'MulFunc': 54, 'SubFunc': NameError("name 'p' is not defined")}
```

To convert to variables:

```
locals().update(solution)
```

Variables would look like:

```
AddFunc = 16, MulFunc = 54, SubFunc = NameError("name 'p' is not defined")
```

Comment: This is an overcomplication to use recursion when we process a single-dimensional iterable! It is much simpler, understandable and probably faster to put `try` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

This definitely isn't the cleanest way of doing it, but you can put it in a while loop with a variable set to true, and when it runs the function successfully it sets the variable to false, whereas if it fails it keeps the variable set to true.

```
x = True
while x == True:
    try:
        do_smth1()
        do_smth2()
        x = False
    except Exception:
        x = True
```

This way what happens is that the while loop will keep on looping the try except section again and again until it works, in which x is set to false and the loop stops

Also, you can implement a break in the while loop instead of basing it on a variable, for example:

```
while True:
    try:
        do_smth1()
        do_smth2()
        break
    except Excpetion:
        pass
```

P.S It is good ettiquete to put a specific exception for the except section, instead of leaving it for any exception. It makes the code cleaner and is more sensible when managing errors especially in bigger projects

Answer (score 0):

If do_smth1() worked, then do_smth2() will not be tried.

```
try:
    x=do_smth1()
except:
    try:
        x=do_smth2()
    except:
        x="Both Failed"

print (x)
```

Answer (score 0):

**this works for me!**

```
for (idx, row) in df.iterrows():

    try:
       ... do something


    except IndexError:
       continue
```