# How to keep iterating after an exception?

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterator

I am confused by interaction between Python-2 iterators and exceptions.

Specifically, given the following code:

```
def gen_int():
    if not hasattr(gen_int,"x"):
        gen_int.x = 0
    while True:
        gen_int.x += 1
        yield gen_int.x

def gen_odd():
    for x in gen_int():
        if x % 2:
            yield x
        else:
            raise ValueError("gen_odd",x)
```

(please assume the above are *out of my control*!), I write

```
def gen_all():
    it = gen_odd()
    while True:
        try:
            yield it.next()
        except ValueError as exn:
            print exn
            func_name, x = exn
            assert func_name == "gen_odd"
            yield x
```

in the hope of recovering the full stream generated by `gen_int`.

However, the iteration stops after the first exception:

```
def gen_test(top):
    for x in gen_all():
        print x
        if x > top:
            break
```

Here are 3 invocations:

```
>>> gen_test(20)
1
('gen_odd', 2)
2
>>> gen_test(20)
3
('gen_odd', 4)
4
>>> gen_test(20)
5
('gen_odd', 6)
6
```

The question is:
**How do I modify `gen_all` so that `gen_test` will print *all* ints below `top`?**

PS. apparently, the exception in `gen_odd` works as `return` - it marks the iterator as exhausted. is this really the case? is there a workaround?

Comment: you can use pass or continue in your try / except

Comment: @tinySandy: could you please be more specific?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python catch exception and continue try block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522990/python-catch-exception-and-continue-try-block)

Comment: @tinySandy: no, this is not a dupe of that question.

Comment: The `it.next` call is raising an Exception afterwards after it handled the exception (on the next iteration). If you add prints around that `it.next` call the print before will be executed three times. Not sure what exception occurs though.

Comment: Why do you `raise` a `ValueError` in the first place in `gen_odd`?

Comment: @Chris_Rands: as I said, `gen_odd` is _out of my control_

Comment: `gen_int` is a strange generator. It saves global state that each new instance uses. The other 99.99% of generators in the wild don't work this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reassign `gen_odd()` in the `except` block:

```
def gen_all():
    it = gen_odd()
    while True:
        try:
            yield it.next()
        except ValueError as exn:
            print exn
            func_name, x = exn
            assert func_name == "gen_odd"
            yield x
            it = gen_odd() # here
```

The generator function `gen_odd` stops once that `ValueError` exception is raised. You have to recall the function to create another gen function object after the previous one stops. `gen_odd` picks up from where it stopped since the yielded values from `gen_int` are bound to the function object; states are saved, else this would not have worked.

---

```
>>> gen_test(5)
1
('gen_odd', 2)
2
3
('gen_odd', 4)
4
5
('gen_odd', 6)
6
```

Comment: This is a great answer but it only works because `gen_int` works off of a singleton `gen_int.x` which means it is saving state outside of the generator. It would not work for the most generators that raise exceptions.

Comment: @tdelaney Yes, I figured the yielded values are bound to the function object, else it would have been very different and probably more difficult