# Continue running to next function with different parameters after exception is caught

Tags: python-3.x, exception, try-catch

I have the following python code;

```
try:
    write_file(param="A")
    write_file(param="B")
    write_file(param="C")
except ValueError:
```

If the first `write_file` raises exception, I want the code to continue to the next `write_file` function. Currently, it runs to the end and stops.

I can't use the answers from a similar question [python catch exception and continue try block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522990/python-catch-exception-and-continue-try-block)
That question uses different function whereas my question uses the same function but with different parameters each time.

I am using python v3.7

Comment: Just turn it around, `for param in ("A", "B", "C"):` then try/except *inside* the loop. That's exactly what the other question's answers show, it doesn't matter that you're looping over a parameter rather than the function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, sorry. I'm a bit slow. Would you mind writing an answer?

Comment: On second thoughts, I think I get what you mean now. Let me try out. thanks.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, One thing I don't understand. Why use `("A", "B", "C")` and not list or set?

Comment: Why not? List or tuple is fine (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25368337/tuple-or-list-when-using-in-in-an-if-clause), a set isn't semantically ordered so may not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question. The credit goes to jonrsharpe who dropped a hint in the comments.

```
    params = ("A", "B", "C")
    for param in params:
        try:
            write_file(param=param)
        except ValueError as ve:
```